# JS createElement parameters with dash

Tags: javascript, parameters, createelement

I'm creating new element with `createElement` function. It works fine. However, I started to use some external SDK, where I need to setup `param-bad` parameter for some elements. But it doesn't work.

Code:

```
  var element = document.createElement("div");
  element.param_good = "value";
  element.param-bad = "value";
```

While I try to add `param-bad` with some value, I get an error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`

Also, `param_good` of course works fine.

How do I work around this?

Comment: `element['param-bad']`

Comment: This has nothing to do with `.createElement`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are wanting to set some attributes to the newly created `div` element. You can do this by using `setAttribute()`.

```js
 let element = document.createElement("div");
 element.setAttribute('param_good', 'value');
 element.setAttribute('param-bad', 'value');
 element.innerHTML = 'Demo text';
 
 document.body.append(element);
```